# HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page,Data is not retrived

Tags: mysql, jsp, tomcat, servlets, glassfish

i am new to tomcat and developed this web application,its work starting fine after some time it gives this error and then i refresh continously it again works,i installed the tomcat,javaEE 6 with glassfish,MY SQL and configured all.can you help me?

Comment: Are there any exceptions in Tomcat's `logs/catalina.out` or any other log file in the `logs/` directory? If so, please post the entire stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to `log` file and can see what might has caused error and then you can trace the 
error 
use the `"log4j.jar"` file . This will generate `"tomcat.log"` in your main Tomcat logs folder, with a 10MB maximum size and a maximum of 10 backups: